# Fibonacci numbers are negative for large inputs

Tags: java, fibonacci

so I have created several Java Fibonacci methods which all have different ways of obtaining fib (ie, recursion, memoization). However, the biggest consistency between each function is that for high input sizes n, i will get a negative Fibonacci number. For example,

```
Input 47 has a fibonacci of: -1323752223 and a time of 1500 nanoseconds //negative??
Input 48 has a fibonacci of: 512559680 and a time of 1400 nanoseconds  //this is positive but wrong?
Input 49 has a fibonacci of: -811192543 and a time of 1400 nanoseconds //negative??
Input 50 has a fibonacci of: -298632863 and a time of 1500 nanoseconds //negative??
```

And for all functions, they have negative values on the **exact** same n (ie, n = 47, n = 49, n = 50).
Why is this, and how can I fix this? All my methods return type **'int'**.

Comment: Use long or BigInteger instead of int

Comment: As an aside: [the 48th fibonacci-numberis `4807526976`, not `512559680`](http://www.maths.surrey.ac.uk/hosted-sites/R.Knott/Fibonacci/fibtable.html)

Comment: Ah, integer overflow. This is why computer architecture classes exist. Always good to know what an int actually is internally.